# Python: 'self' is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, dictionary, self, class-variables

I have a class with a multiple dictionary variables. Is there a way to set the dictionary parameter of the class variable where variable name is passed as a string in a function?

```
<?php
class Test:
    var1 = { "value": 1 }
    var2 = { "value": 2 }

    def set_variable(self, var_name, value):
        ## self.var_name.value = value ### pylint: Instance of 'Test' has no 'var_name' member
        self[var_name]["value"] = value ### pylint: 'self' is unsubscriptable ###

instance = Test()
instance.set_variable("var1", 150)
```

While coding the linter throws error stating: " 'self' is unsubscriptable". If I execute the code, I get the error: " TypeError: 'Test' object is not subscriptable".

One way to fix this problem is by creating a temporary variable using 'getattr':

```
    def set_variable(self, var_name, value):
        temp = getattr(self, var_name)
        temp["value"] = value
        setattr(self, var_name, temp)
```

But, I find the above to be an ugly solution increasing memory usage especially for much bigger dictionaries.

Also, I would like to use self[var_name] at many places. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`

Comment: If var1 and var2 are class variables, why isn't set_variable a class method?

Comment: set_variable is a class method! Didn't you read the code?

Comment: @JamesAntony Izaak means that `set_variable` is an instance method (operating on an instance, `self`), but your `var1`, `var2` are class variables (basically, they are shared among all instances). To get instance variables, something like `def __init__(self): self.var1 = ...` is needed.

Comment: I see, understood. @Izaak: Apologies.. This was just a quick example to get solution to use self[key] syntax, the original implementation is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Python classes are implemented using dictionaries, you can't treat them as dictionaries out of the box.

`self[var_name]` should be `getattr(self, var_name)`.

If you insist on using `[ ]` syntax `Test` should implement `__getitem__`:

```
class Test:
    var1 = { "value": 1 }
    var2 = { "value": 2 }

    def set_variable(self, var_name, value):
        self[var_name]["value"] = value
        # or getattr(self, var_name)["value"] = value if not implementing __getitem__

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)

instance = Test()
instance.set_variable("var1", 150)
print(instance.var1)
#  {'value': 150}
```

Comment: Using __getitem__ looks perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`setattr(self, var_name, temp)` is not needed, since you are modifying the original dictionary (you just name it `temp` for a while). Here it is essentially a no-op (you are setting the same address of the dictionary that you have read). So the memory usage is tiny and doesn't depend on how large your dictionary is.

So the solution you were close to is:

```
def set_variable(self, var_name, value):
    getattr(self, var_name)["value"] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.__dict__[var_name]` to do what you want.